# Is a DNS packet with only a header (no questions or resources) valid?

Tags: dns, packet, network-protocols

Looking at [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) I am trying to determine what the proper response is for a packet that contains nothing but a DNS header, where all the "counts" are zero:

```
id         short     X
qdcount    short     0
ancount    short     0
nscount    short     0
arcount    short     0
<EOF>
```

Should this packet have any response? Should it be considered an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any DNS query where `qdcount` is not equal to `1` should be rejected by the DNS server.

The returned error will most likely be "Format Error" (FORMERR, rcode=1),
which is only logical, since a DNS query for nothing at all must be considered
as malformed.

Finding official sources for this is pretty hard.
I did find for the NSD server a
[bug report](https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/bugs-script/show_bug.cgi?id=721)
where it was tested and remarked : "QDCOUNT=0 makes it FORMERR".

For the BIND server, StackOverflow post
[What does QD stand for in DNS RFC1035](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031349/what-does-qd-stand-for-in-dns-rfc1035)
says this about QDCOUNT:

> note that this field is useless now, because BIND has always rejected QDCOUNT != 1.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially depends on the opcode specified in the header (there are several – query, notify, update, etc.) For regular queries [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) says:

> A standard query specifies a target domain name (QNAME), query type (QTYPE), and query class (QCLASS) and asks for RRs which match.

I would interpret the use of the singular "target" etc. as a query always having exactly one record in the question section; anything else should return FORMERR.

There are variations (e.g. the obsolete IQUERY uses queries with at least one record in answer section, but empty question section), but I couldn't find any opcodes which would allow all sections to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a 'meaningless QUERY'. (Have no actual experience to validate this.)

RFC-2671 section 4.5.4

> The responder's maximum payload size can change over time, but
> can be reasonably expected to remain constant between two
> sequential transactions; for example, a meaningless QUERY to
> discover a responder's maximum UDP payload size, followed
> immediately by an UPDATE which takes advantage of this size.